# How to perform row operations in R to produce a single statistic

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to compute a mean from a data frame in R. The file represents the output of coverage (column 4) over ranges (columns 2,3) of a chromosome (column 1).

The data looks like this:

```
V1  V2  V3   V4
 1  65  69  103
 1  69  70  107
 1  70  74  108
 1  74  75  110
 1  75  77  111
 1  77  78  113
 1  78  79  115
 1  79  80  118
 1  80  81  119
```

I want to compute the mean coverage over all of the file. On paper, this looks like:
[103*(69-65)+107(70-69)+108(74-70)+ ... + V4(V3-V2)]/(lengthOfChromosome)

The lengthOfChromosome is known.

I've been searching for a solution, and the closest thing I've found is the row-wise operators in the `apply()` family. These don't seem particularly well suited for the task since most of their outputs appear to be either matrices or lists or vectors. My goal is to get a single statistic: the mean. I also might be interested in the standard deviation, but that is less important now.

Any tips in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: The (-1) is a bit harsh - there clearly has been research effort and it is not unclear to solve, as evidenced by the 2 answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `apply()` here. Most operators in R operate in a vectorized manner. So if your data is in a data.frame called `dd`

```
dd<-structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V2 = c(65L, 
69L, 70L, 74L, 75L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L), V3 = c(69L, 70L, 74L, 
75L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L), V4 = c(103L, 107L, 108L, 110L, 
111L, 113L, 115L, 118L, 119L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Then you can get the numerator of your equation with a simple

```
with(dd, sum(V4*(V3-V2)))
```

(here we use `with()` so we don't have to write `dd$` a bunch of times.) And assuming the lenght of the chromosome is just the max end less the min start then

```
with(dd, sum(V4*(V3-V2))/(max(V3)-min(V2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `dat` is your data.frame and if `V1` is only `1`:

```
with(dat, sum(V4*(V3-V2))) / (lengthOfChromosome)
```